# eigenvalue of a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is singular, why is 0 an eigenvalue of $A$? Also, if 0 is an eigenvalue of $A$, then why is $A$ singular?

I don't quite understand the reasoning between the relationship of a 0 eigenvalue and a singular matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is singular we have:

\begin{equation}
Av=0, v\ne0
\end{equation}

so $v$ satisfies $Av=\lambda v=0$ where $\lambda$ it is the eigenvalue ($\lambda=0$).